# Catch the LuaSQL error to the xpcall error handler function

Tags: lua, luasql

How can I get the error output from the LuaSQL driver as an argument to the `xpcall error` function as assert does?

For example, by running the following code:

```lua
local conn =  assert (env:connect("demo_database",config.db.username,config.db.password,config.db.host))
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
LuaSQL: error connecting to database. MySQL: Access denied for user 'user_1'@'host1' (using password: YES)
```

But when I'm running the following code:

```lua
local function myerrorhandler( err )
    local file = assert( io.open( "/tmp/testout.txt", "w" ) )
    file:write( err.." - error\n" )
    file:close()
end

local conn = xpcall (env:connect("demo_database",config.db.username,config.db.password,config.db.host), myerrorhandler)
```

The error I'm getting in the log file is: `attempt to call a nil value - error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xpcall` expects the first argument to be a function, which it will call and catch errors from. You are basically doing `xpcall(func(), handler)`, i.e. calling `func` instead of just passing it to `xpcall`, similar to how `pcall` expects a function as first argument.

You basically want to wrap your code in a function:

```lua
local conn = xpcall(function()
    return env:connect("demo_database", config.db.username, config.db.password, config.db.host)
end, myerrorhandler)
```